# Report Suddenly Stopped Returning Data

Tags: reporting, urlhacking

An important report that I created suddenly stopped working entirely. It used to show us all the items an `Account` has purchased, but now it shows nothing unless you remove the `Account` ID, then it shows items purchased for all accounts (as you would expect it to).

The `Account` ID is supplied through a URL hack. A custom button on each `Account` page picks up the `Account` ID just fine and passes it into the report's account ID filter, but now there are no results when it worked perfectly before.

The report is not complicated. It simply return all the records for an `Account` ID from the custom object `Invoice Lines`, which is data from our ERP. `Account` and `Invoice Lines` are linked together via the `Invoice Header` custom object.

I did not change any of the relationships or the custom report type this report is based on. I recreated the report with the same results. I need advice on how to troubleshoot this further.

Schema screenshot: http://cardboardsword.net/ss.jpg

Comment: Has anything else changed in your instance?  For example, has Lightning been turned on?

Comment: @Jagular A bunch more data was added from our ERP. Other than that, no nothing has changed.

Comment: has the report hierarchy used changed for the running user ?

Comment: @crop1645 No that hasn't been touched in awhile

Comment: so this report uses external objects?